# how to get callback when scrollTo mCustomScrollbar or run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mcustomscrollbar

how to get alert when scrollTo mCustomScrollbar or run function

```
$('.section-wrap').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", 0, {
    scrollInertia: 1500,
    scrollEasing: "easeOut",
    callback:{
        alert()  or somefunc ();
    }       
});

function somefunc(){
    alert();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `onScroll` or some other callback:

```
jQuery('.section-wrap').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", 0, {
    scrollInertia: 1500,
    scrollEasing: "easeOut",
    callbacks: {
        onScroll: function() {
            // your code
            alert('content scrolled...');
        }
    }
});
```